# Regarind an Heap Size error

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

When I'm running a program which is used to read an video I'm getting an error referring to Heapsize which is shown below:

EAP[videodemo34.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlSizeHeap( 04EC0000, 00254CE8 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in videodemo34.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, and indicates a bug in videodemo34.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

The output window may have more diagnostic information

can anyone say about it?

Comment: Without any sample code everybody will be purely guessing. As I commented on the previous question, why don't you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted some code with your questions Prashanth (refer to one of your other threads).

Anyway it is doubtful that this is a bug as it clearly states that a breakpoint has been triggered in your code.

This will most likely be because you are running a debug executable with embedded breakpoints.